# Is there a way to call UIDAI (Aadhaar) API from PHP?

Tags: php

How can I do Aadhar Authentication using UIDAI APIs within a web site? There is Java/Python code present, but not for PHP. So can we use cURL to call them in PHP code? Is there another solution available (apart from cURL calling) to use existing codes provided by UIDAI and integrate it with PHP code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377015/how-to-integrate-aadhaar-card-authentication-api-for-aadhaar-number-verification

Comment: I have added working code in php on link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377015/how-to-integrate-aadhaar-card-authentication-api-for-aadhaar-number-verification

Comment: @Jyotie Navale Can you please tell me how could i get the values of encrypted and encoded session key in Skey, encrypted PID block in data, SHA-256 Hash of Pid block, encrypted and then encoded in Hmac and Digital signature in Signature ? I have gone through the documentation but no idea how could i got these values