# How do i generate input data for Aadhar card (used by indian citizen as their unique identifier) API integration

Tags: php, xml, public-key-encryption

I am implementing aadhar card api and I got stuck in generating PID and sKey xml block for input xml data, following is the requirement for both key element.

PID block data should be encrypted with a dynamic session key using AES-256 symmetric algorithm (AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding). Session key, in turn, is encrypted with 2048-bit UIDAI public key using asymmetric algorithm (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding).

Skey Value of this element is base-64 encoded value of encrypted 256-bit AES session key.

Below is the code what I have created:

```
 /////////////////////

$ci = '20170922';       

$method = 'AES-256-ECB';
$skey = openssl_encrypt (session_id(), $method ,$ci, true);

$pid_block = '<Pid ts="2016061512000000" ver="1.0"><Demo lang=""><Pi ms="E" mv="" name="Shivshankar Choudhury" lname="" lmv="" gender="" dob="" dobt="" age="" phone="" email="" /></Demo></Pid>';
$pid_encoded = base64_encode($pid_block);
$hash_256_pid = hash (  'sha256'  ,  $pid_block);
$hmac_pid_block = openssl_encrypt($hash_256_pid , $method , session_id());
$encoded_hmac_pid_block = base64_encode($hmac_pid_block);


$xml_data = '<Auth ac="public" sa="public" ver="1.6" txn="706bf70d" tid="public" uid="999999990019"><Uses pi="y" pa="n" pfa="n" bio="y" bt="FMR" otp="n" pin="n"/><Meta udc="UIDAI:SampleClient" fdc="NC" idc="NA" pip="127.0.0.1" lot="P" lov="560103"/><Skey ci="20131003" >'.$skey.'</Skey><Data type="X">'.$pid_encoded.'</Data><Hmac>'.$encoded_hmac_pid_block.'</Hmac></Auth>';
echo $xml_data;
$url = "http://auth.uidai.gov.in/1.6/public/9/9/";

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    "xmlRequest=" . $xml_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        //convert the XML result into array
        $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To integrate Aadhaar Card Authentication Api for Aadhaar number Verification in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377015/how-to-integrate-aadhaar-card-authentication-api-for-aadhaar-number-verification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered at below link for PHP.

[How To integrate Aadhaar Card Authentication Api for Aadhaar number Verification in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377015/how-to-integrate-aadhaar-card-authentication-api-for-aadhaar-number-verification)

If you are going to use java, to generate skey(32characters,256 bit) in AES and then encrypting it, You need to use bouncycastle jar. This is because java by default has limit of 128 bit(16 charcaters) limit and then encode it.

You can find the sample code in uidai developer portal